# Can I display certain markers in Leaflet (in Rstudio) based on the presence of certain characters?

Tags: r

I have a leaflet map with markers based on presence/absence data for different species.  I'd like to be able to have a menu of species to select from, and the map would only display the markers of sites where that species is present (for example, select species B and the markers for 2 and 4 would be hidden).  Is there a way to accomplish this without creating and individual layer for each site? I have about 100 sites in my actual data.

````
df<-data.frame(sites,longitude,latitude,speciesA,speciesB,speciesC)
site_name<-function(k){
  df[df$sites==k, ]
}
species_present<-function(h){
  subset(h, select = speciesA:speciesC) |>
    sapply(function(z) all(z == 1)) |> which() |> names()
}
marker<-function(b){
  species_present(site_name(b))
}
marker_list<-lapply(as.list(df$sites),marker)
class(marker_list)<-"character"
new_df<-df[ ,c("sites","longitude","latitude")]
df_3<-cbind(new_df,marker_list)
leaflet()%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  setView(lng=-78,lat=44,zoom=5)%>%
  addMarkers(df_3,lng=df_3$longitude,lat=df_3$latitude,popup = paste(
    df_3$sites
    ,"<br>"
    ,df_3$marker_list))```

I have explored the solution laid out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063343/22801263, but I'm not sure how I could apply it to my map given that I'm looking to filter out data based on the presence of a character rather than the value of a continuous variable.  
My eventual goal is to make an app using rShiny, so if there is a solution within Shiny itself I am very much open to that as well.  The presence/absence data for the species in question will be updated annually, so I am hoping to have a map that can be updated simply by changing the species in the matrix without heavily editing the code for the map itself each time.
````

Comment: Can you share the `df` dataframe?